# Как исправить ошибку в dll-библиотеке WindowsBase фреймфорка Mono на Mac?

Tags: c#, dll, mac, mono, monodevelop

Написал небольшую программку для обработки xlsx таблиц, при выполнении ругается

```
Unhandled Exception:
        System.IO.IOException: Operation not valid when package is read-only
        at System.IO.Packaging.Package.CheckIsReadOnly () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/Package.cs:113 
        at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.CreateRelationship (System.Uri targetUri, TargetMode targetMode, System.String relationshipType, System.String id, Boolean loading) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/PackagePart.cs:128 
        at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.LoadRelationships (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 relationships, System.IO.Stream stream) [0x0008f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/PackagePart.cs:168 
        at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.get_Relationships () [0x00048] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/PackagePart.cs:50 
        at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetRelationships () [0x00016] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/PackagePart.cs:192 
        at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.PackagePartRelationshipPropertyCollection..ctor (System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart packagePart) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart.Load (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage openXmlPackage, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart parent, System.Uri uriTarget, System.String id, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 loadedParts) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.LoadReferencedPartsAndRelationships (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage openXmlPackage, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart sourcePart, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.RelationshipCollection relationshipCollection, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 loadedParts) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Load () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.IOException: Operation not valid when package is read-only
        at System.IO.Packaging.Package.CheckIsReadOnly () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/Package.cs:113 
        at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.CreateRelationship (System.Uri targetUri, TargetMode targetMode, System.String relationshipType, System.String id, Boolean loading) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/PackagePart.cs:128 
        at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.LoadRelationships (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 relationships, System.IO.Stream stream) [0x0008f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/PackagePart.cs:168 
        at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.get_Relationships () [0x00048] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/PackagePart.cs:50 
        at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetRelationships () [0x00016] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/PackagePart.cs:192 
        at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.PackagePartRelationshipPropertyCollection..ctor (System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart packagePart) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart.Load (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage openXmlPackage, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart parent, System.Uri uriTarget, System.String id, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 loadedParts) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.LoadReferencedPartsAndRelationships (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage openXmlPackage, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart sourcePart, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.RelationshipCollection relationshipCollection, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 loadedParts) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Load () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

        Press any key to continue...
```

Судя по [этому топику](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/39), проблема заключается в *dll*-библиотеке `WindowsBase`, которую исправил вот [этим коммитом](https://github.com/dmunch/mono/commit/bee81085af07a3ef1f64c024924be63f7b0f344c).

Как мне исправить эту же ошибку у себя?

Подходящий редактор *dll*-библиотек не нашел под *мак*, а при попытке самостоятельно сколотить *dll* из скачанного с *гита* архива, где уже исправлена ошибка, компилятор выдает кучу ошибок, и даже не хочет строить.

Comment: Почему не скопировать сразу сюда весь открытий в winDbg дамп...

Comment: Хм. В мире open source должна быть альтернатива ожиданию патча.

Comment: Проблема видимо в сборке исправленной dll? Присылайте ссылку на Git и ошибки компиляции.